# Webpack loader support needed in npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, npm, webpack

I am trying to find the unused depenecies. So I am using the depcheck-es6 package 
but we have one issue with this package
https://github.com/lijunle/depcheck-es6/issues/14
Even the owner of this package need help
can you guys tell how to fix it

**It does not recognise the loaders in the webpack config file. How to recognise the dependencies in the loaders file. This feature depcheck-es6 package doesnot support. How to support it**

```
 module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }, {
      test: /\.css?$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'raw'],
      include: __dirname
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: not really sure what the problem is.  are you saying that you can't dep check because your code has special webpack requires?

Comment: @4m1r we need to make additional code changes to make it work for webpack dependencies...you can details about the issue here https://github.com/lijunle/depcheck-es6/issues/14

Comment: sorry, I really can't follow the thread.  can you edit the above with an example of what you've been trying?

Comment: @4m1r thanks for your reply, updated question, can you help me now

Comment: your webpack config looks fine.  are you using a particular extension that's not being resolved?  what is the error from webpack?

Comment: @4m1r webpack is fine but the problem is depcheck-es6 is not identifying the unused dependencies in webpack loader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93416/discussion-between-texi-rv03-and-4m1r).